# What does the shifting of graded modules mean here?

Tags: commutative-algebra, graded-modules

> For any graded module $M$ we denote $M(a)$ the module $M$ "shifted by $a$" so that $M(a)_d=M_{a+d}$. **Thus for example the free $S$-module of rank $1$ generated by an element of degree $a$ is $S(-a)$**.

Here $S=k[x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n]$, where $k$ is a field.

I don't understand the statement in bold font. We know that $S=M_0\oplus M_1\oplus\dots\oplus M_n$ where $M_d$ is the group of homogeneous polynomials of degree $d$. Hence $S(-a)=M_{-a}\oplus M_{-a+1}\oplus \dots\oplus M_{n-a}$

What does this even mean?

Answer (score 2):

That's almost right.  But, note that
$$
S = \bigoplus_{d=0}^{\infty}M_d = M_0 \oplus M_1 \oplus \ldots
$$

not the finite direct sum that you wrote.

But the next thing you wrote is a little more wrong.  The point is that after shifting, the $d$ degree part of $S(-a)$ is whatever the $d-a$ graded part of $S$ is, ie. $M_{d-a}$ if $a\leq d$ or $0$ otherwise.   But don't forget, at this point, we're talking about $S(-a)$ as a module over $S$, not as a ring.  It IS in fact a ring, but we're thinking of it as the free module with generator in degree $a$ in this case.

Comment: Sorry, shouldn't it read "the $d$ degree part of $S(-a)$ is whatever the $d$ graded part of $S$ is"?

Comment: Also, is this module equal to $S$? I feel it should be a subset of $S$. Sorry this is an irrelevant question. I am just clarifying

Comment: Also, what does degree of an element mean here? Let us suppose an element $b$ has degree $a$. Does it mean $b$ is a monomial of degree $a$? Or does it mean $b^a=1$?

Comment: Hi Ayush.  Let's take this to chat.  The answer to your questions is all no, but will take longer than a comment to explain. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/35119/discussion-between-ayush-and-callus?tab=general

Comment: Thanks! Sounds like a good idea. However, how do I take this conversation to chat?

Comment: Click on the link in my comment.  That should take you to the room